# With Ninject, Is there a equivalent of Structuremap WhatDoIHave

Tags: ninject

I'm new to Ninject and I'm looking for a way to get the container bindings like we can do it with StructureMap using the `WhatDoIHave` method.

Do you know if it exists and if not, what can I do to get the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IMyService));
```

Comment: Getting the scope is not easy. You can call the scope call back and pass null. But his will not work for all scope types but the default ones should be ok.

Comment: OK. I don't know if it's something you consider to add to Ninject but it would be a great addon to help to find injection problems.

Comment: It's technically not possible as the scope is requested using a callback. While static scopes like InSingletonScope and InTransientScope do not care about the context others like InRequestScope or InNamedScope do.

Comment: @Remo Gloor @mberube.Net : What does the debugger show for the scope callback. As far as I'm aware, it should be clear with a pdb as theyre generally small helper methods with names

Comment: I didn't check with the debugger but I'm pretty sure it is a anonymous Func<IContext, object>

Comment: @Remov Gloor: Makes sense. I guess you'd have to make it pretty ugly and add an intermediarly layer with associated delegate classes. I give up!